# How I visit website by inet address

Tags: networking, server, wordpress

I am new at ubuntu server. I install wordpress on ubuntu server using virtualbox on windows 7. Everything correct seems to me but I can’t visit by typing inet address on the browser. N.B I change dhcp to static ip . I have gotten address by ping 127.0.0.1

My questions - Is it possible to install Wordpress on ubuntu server using virtualbox then visit from windows installed owser?
What would possible my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible to run WordPress inside a virtual machine on your computer and access a WordPress website from the VM in your computer's webbrowser.

Your problem could be a Virtualbox network setup issue. Or even a firewall issue on your virtual machine in Ubuntu. Hard to tell from your info.

If you're new to VM/Ubuntu/WordPress and would like to get things up and running real quick, I suggest downloading and using a pre-configured virtual machine that has almost everything set up the right way already – like this [bitnami WordPress Virtual Machines](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/virtual-machine) for example. You just have to complete Network setup for your virtual machine in Virtualbox. But they have good how-tos and readmes for this on their page.

This way you get good results fast. And you can still setup your own server from scratch later after you gained more experience with the whole topic.